# Iframe doesnt work

Tags: php, html, iframe

Thanks for the information about header troubles. One more question: Can i know if there are header issues preventing me show it in an iframe just from the link itself? So i will show a different page for the problematic sites?

I have a page where i include another website.
The code is:

```
<iframe id="frameId" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="80%" src="<?php echo $deal_URL ?>">Cant open the iframe</iframe>
```

The problem is that sometimes the iframe is not shown on the page.
I inspect it with chrome "inspect element" and i have found out that between the tags

```
<iframe> </iframe>
```

I also have html.

```
<iframe id="frameId" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="80%" src="<?php echo $deal_URL ?>">
#document
<html>....</html>
</iframe>
```

Mostly it happens with amazon links.

How i can present their site? Is there other solution than iframe?

Tried solution:
I tried John solution and created another php file. My original file looks:

```
<iframe id="frameId" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="80%" src='PresentFrame.php?URL=<?php echo     $deal_URL ?>'> Cant open the iframe</iframe>
```

And in new PresentFrame.php i wrote:

```
<?php  
$URL=$_GET['URL'];
echo file_get_contents("$URL");
?>
```

It works as in : presents some info but now it looks very bad. Pictures are not presented and it doesnt look like a website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon uses the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` HTTP header which tells browsers not to allow its pages to be served in frames. Your only other option is to load the data server side (`file_get_contents()`) and then passthru the contents.

Comment: so you say nothing is wrong with my code and there is nothing i can do if i have a link to an website that dont allow iframes?

Comment: Correct. `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` is designed to block exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: Can you explain the option you gave: "Your only other option is to load the data server side and then passthru the contents."?

Comment: You can load a page from your own site in the iframe and use `file_get_contents()` on that page to fetch the page you want from the other site and then echo it out effectively bypassing this header.

Comment: I have tried your solution (look at my edited question) but it doesnt behave well

Comment: You probably have path issues. If they are referencing images and css files without specifying their domain in the URL those paths will not work. You will need to parse their code and add it yourself. Unfortunately it adds a layer of complexity but it's what you have to do if you really want to frame their content.

Comment: Thanks for the information. One more question: Can i know if there are header issues preventing me show it in an iframe just from the link itself? So i will show a different page for the problematic sites?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something in the $deal_URL every time?

And you should not use uppercase on the attributes...

```
<iframe id="frameId" width="100%" height="80%" src="<?php echo $deal_URL ?>">
```

Comment: I do and the problem is what John said... I just wonder what to do. I have to present product information on one page now i cant